# Why are the value for Hosted Zone ID different for ELB and Route 53 Alias Target?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

Here is my load balancer Sid-LB - the Hosted Zone ID is highlighted:

[image]

And this is the Route 53 (hosted zone id is highlighted) when I select the load balancer from Alias Target.

[image]

I dont understand why these two IDs have to be different. I tried to send an API call with the payload (containing the ELB hosted zone id) to create the record set, which it creates but doesnt work. How is this Alias Hosted Zone ID for Route 53 generated and does it have any connection with the ELB Hosted Zone ID??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot create a record set with Hosted Zone ID as given by the endpoint, as it is not the correct mapping. We need the Alias Hosted Zone ID to map correctly.

Since it (Alias Hosted Zone ID for Route53) is generated automatically and there is no api call for getting that ID, the only workaround is to create a CNAME record set with value as the ELB endpoint (or S3 bucket endpoint or CloudFront endpoint).

Answer (score 9):

You can get the Hosted Zone ID of Elastic Load Balancing here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elb.html

In your case I can see that the Hosted Zone ID is the one for US West (Oregon) - us-west-2.

Comment: @Mobigital The URL changed I edited the answer with the new URL.

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html#rrsets-values-alias-hosted-zone-id) are a little vague about this:

> This value appears automatically based on the value that you selected or entered for Alias Target.

However, the Alias Hosted Zone ID is not the same as the Hosted Zone ID. To create an Alias record, you just need the Hosted Zoned ID. Check out some of the sample requests provided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets_Requests.html). They all take a HostedZoneId parameter.

So for your use case, I think you can just ignore it. All you need to know is that the 'Hosted Zone ID' and an Alias record's 'Alias Hosted Zone ID' are not the same thing.

Comment: I tried that already. It is creates the record set with the Hosted Zone ID but it is not working- i.e. the record set is not mapped to the ELB.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic BeanStalk use apart Hosted Zone ID list from Route 53 zone ID list.

Use this link to find you ELB Zone ID:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/general/latest/gr/elasticbeanstalk.html